# I need help merging two rows based on certain string character, the string is complaint

Tags: r, string, dplyr, merge, character

I am trying to calculate the fraction of the construction noise per zip code across NY city. The data is from NYC 311.

I am using dplyr and have grouped the data per zip.
However, I am finding difficulties merging the row for the complain column, I have to merge the data as per the string "construction" it appear anywhere meaning middle, front or end.

My solution, this is just the beginning

```
comp_types <- df %>% select(complaint_type,descriptor,incident_zip) %>% 
    group_by(incident_zip)
```

can you help me merge the row if unique value in descriptor contains any construction value.

Comment: Please show few rows of data with `dput(head(df, 10))` and your expected output

Comment: Could you post reproducible example?

Comment: Descriptor               Com. Proportion
Loud Music/Party 141 0.141  
Banging/Pounding 88 0.088  
ENTIRE BUILDING 85 0.085  
Blocked Hydrant 72 0.072  
No Access 59 0.059  
APARTMENT ONLY 44 0.044  
Commercial Overnight Parking 32 0.032  
Loud Talking 31 0.031  
N/A 28 0.028  
Posted Parking Sign Violation 27 0.027

Comment: I have to merge the first row based on the element "music" in the row observation and get the complaints counts which is the second column

Comment: When you use `dput(head(df, 10))`, can you copy the output that starts with `structure` and paste it into your original question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clarify what you mean by "merging"? I don't think you actually want to [`merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941677/merging-two-data-frames) because you only have one dataframe. The term "merging" is used to describe the joining of two dataframes.

See `?base::merge`:

> Merge two data frames by common columns or row names, or do other versions of database join operations.

If I understand correctly, you want to look into the `descriptor` variable and see if it contains the string "construction" anywhere in the cell, so you can determine if the person's complaint was construction-related; same for "music". I don't believe you need to use `complaint_type` since `complaint_type` never contains the string "construction" or "music"; only `descriptor` does.

You can use a combination of `ifelse` and [`grepl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850026/filter-rows-which-contain-a-certain-string) to create a new variable that indicates whether the complaint was construction-related, music-related, or other.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
url <- "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/p5f6-bkga/rows.csv"
df <- read.csv(url, nrows = 10000) %>%
  clean_names() %>%
  select(complaint_type, descriptor, incident_zip)

comp_types <- df %>% 
  select(complaint_type, descriptor, incident_zip) %>% 
  group_by(incident_zip) 
head(comp_types)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#> # Groups:   incident_zip [6]
#>   complaint_type      descriptor                                   incident_zip
#>   <chr>               <chr>                                               <int>
#> 1 Noise - Residential Banging/Pounding                                    11364
#> 2 Noise - Residential Loud Music/Party                                    11222
#> 3 Noise - Residential Banging/Pounding                                    10033
#> 4 Noise - Residential Loud Music/Party                                    11208
#> 5 Noise - Residential Loud Music/Party                                    10037
#> 6 Noise               Noise: Construction Before/After Hours (NM1)        11238

table(df$complaint_type)
#> 
#>                    Noise       Noise - Commercial       Noise - Helicopter 
#>                      555                      591                      145 
#> Noise - House of Worship             Noise - Park      Noise - Residential 
#>                       20                       72                     5675 
#>  Noise - Street/Sidewalk          Noise - Vehicle 
#>                     2040                      902

df <- df %>%
  mutate(descriptor_misc = ifelse(grepl("Construction", descriptor), "Construction", 
                            ifelse(grepl("Music", descriptor), "Music", "Other")))

df %>%
  group_by(descriptor_misc) %>%
  count()
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#> # Groups:   descriptor_misc [3]
#>   descriptor_misc     n
#>   <chr>           <int>
#> 1 Construction      328
#> 2 Music            6354
#> 3 Other            3318

head(df)
#>        complaint_type                                   descriptor incident_zip
#> 1 Noise - Residential                             Banging/Pounding        11364
#> 2 Noise - Residential                             Loud Music/Party        11222
#> 3 Noise - Residential                             Banging/Pounding        10033
#> 4 Noise - Residential                             Loud Music/Party        11208
#> 5 Noise - Residential                             Loud Music/Party        10037
#> 6               Noise Noise: Construction Before/After Hours (NM1)        11238
#>   descriptor_misc
#> 1           Other
#> 2           Music
#> 3           Other
#> 4           Music
#> 5           Music
#> 6    Construction
```

Comment: If you feel that I've appropriately answered your question, don't forget to click the green checkmark next to my answer.